# Failing to connect to Spark Master: Reason is: [Disassociated]

Tags: java, apache-spark, akka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to connect to a Spark Cluster on my local machine from an Eclipse Rich Platform application to create a Spark Streaming Context. Connecting from the spark shell works flawlessly but when i try to run the code from the class I'm working on this is the result:

```
 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://host:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

Clearly the host is identical to the one I'm using in the Spark Shell.

This is the block of code where I try to connect to Spark.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkNode")
        .setMaster("spark://host:7077").set("spark.akka.heartbeat.interval", "100");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc,Durations.seconds(3));
ssc.awaitTermination();
```

It retries a few times and then terminates.

Comment: have you checked your master. If your setup in local system , --master local[2] will be the master and the url mentioned in your master script might not be right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be version problem your spark server might be 1.3 while your have dependency of 1.4 in pom file if using maven or have jar file for 1.4 please cross reference it and in code

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkNode")
        .setMaster("spark://host:7077").set("spark.akka.heartbeat.interval", "100");
```

spark://host:7077
this host should be hostname

Comment: Yeah, there was a different scala version in my sbt file. Now I need to understand how to fix this in my working enviroment with the custom JRE I have to work with. Thanks.

Comment: @Chobeat Here is [link](http://paxcel.net/blog/how-to-setup-apache-spark-standalone-cluster-on-multiple-machine/) to setup spark on multiple machines